# How do I move up/down a highlight selected row from a table in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in angularjs, I'm trying to do a table to move up/down the selected highlight row with buttons..

for example, after select the first row I need to change it to the second position with a down button...

I really need help!

```js
var foodApp = angular.module('foodApp',[]);

foodApp.controller('foodCtrl',function($scope){
 $scope.selectedRow = null;
 $scope.foodItems = [{
  name:'Noodles',
  price:'10',
  quantity:'1'
 },
 {
  name:'Pasta',
  price:'20',
  quantity:'2'
 },
 {
  name:'Pizza',
  price:'30',
  quantity:'1'
 },
 {
  name:'Chicken tikka',
  price:'100',
  quantity:'1'
 }];
 $scope.setClickedRow = function(index){
  $scope.selectedRow = index;
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
.selected {
 background-color:black;
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
<html>
 <head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/> 
 </head>
 <body ng-app="foodApp" ng-controller="foodCtrl">
  <table class="table table-bordered" >
   <tr>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
   </tr>
   <tr ng-repeat="item in foodItems" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
    <td>{{$index}}</td>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.price}}</td>
    <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <div>
   selectedRow = {{selectedRow}}
  </div>
 <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="js/foodCtrl.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are your buttons?  Do you mean arrow keys?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit the code, I mean <button></button>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use some `ng-click` directives and add appropriate handlers to your controller.

```js
var foodApp = angular.module('foodApp', []);

foodApp.controller('foodCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.selectedRow = null;
  $scope.foodItems = [{
    name: 'Noodles',
    price: '10',
    quantity: '1'
  }, {
    name: 'Pasta',
    price: '20',
    quantity: '2'
  }, {
    name: 'Pizza',
    price: '30',
    quantity: '1'
  }, {
    name: 'Chicken tikka',
    price: '100',
    quantity: '1'
  }];
  $scope.setClickedRow = function(index) {
    $scope.selectedRow = index;
  }
  $scope.moveUp = function(num) {
    if (num > 0) {
      tmp = $scope.foodItems[num - 1];
      $scope.foodItems[num - 1] = $scope.foodItems[num];
      $scope.foodItems[num] = tmp;
      $scope.selectedRow--;
    }
  }
  $scope.moveDown = function(num) {
    if (num < $scope.foodItems.length - 1) {
      tmp = $scope.foodItems[num + 1];
      $scope.foodItems[num + 1] = $scope.foodItems[num];
      $scope.foodItems[num] = tmp;
      $scope.selectedRow++;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .selected {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
  <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
</head>

<body ng-app="foodApp" ng-controller="foodCtrl">
  <table class="table table-bordered" ng-keydown="key($event)">
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in foodItems" ng-class="{'selected':$index == selectedRow}" ng-click="setClickedRow($index)">
      <td>{{$index}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.price}}</td>
      <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" ng-click="moveUp(selectedRow)">Move Up</button>
  <button type="button" ng-click="moveDown(selectedRow)">Move Down</button>
  <div>
    selectedRow = {{selectedRow}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir! that really helped me.

Comment: @AlvaroEnrique Glad to help.  If this solved your issue, be sure to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The avobe answer of **zero298** works perfect. But just a small correction

**Senario** -
If you click on the Move Up or Move Down button without selecting a row then it creates a empty row.

[image]

**Solution** -
NULL check for $scope.selectedRow

```
    $scope.moveUp = function(num) {
    if (num > 0 && $scope.selectedRow != null) {
      tmp = $scope.foodItems[num - 1];
      $scope.foodItems[num - 1] = $scope.foodItems[num];
      $scope.foodItems[num] = tmp;
      $scope.selectedRow--;
    }
  }
  $scope.moveDown = function(num) {
    if (num < $scope.foodItems.length - 1 && $scope.selectedRow != null) {
      tmp = $scope.foodItems[num + 1];
      $scope.foodItems[num + 1] = $scope.foodItems[num];
      $scope.foodItems[num] = tmp;
      $scope.selectedRow++;
    }
  }
```